# Unable to create knowledgebase for azure cognitive service (Error: "No Endpoint keys found.")

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I am creating a new knowledge base connecting it to an already existing Azure Cognitive Service. But I am getting error: "No Endpoint keys found." when i click "Create KB".

See capture of the error:

[image: Error]

My QnAMaker cognitive service has the endpoint
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are connected with the same account between QnA Maker portal (1st capture) and Azure portal (2nd capture)?

Comment: @Nicloas: yes..

Comment: Are you working in a multi-tenant environment, by chance?

Comment: @MaheshGali Did you solve this issue? I am having the same problem with a QnAMaker that I created via ARM templates.

Comment: It was an issue with azure resource. We got a new one created and it worked fine i.e. we could create knowledge base successfully. @OffHeGoes

Answer (score 3):

It seems that there is sometimes the problem that the endpoint keys can only be found, if the Resource Group holding all resources for the QnA Maker Service (*like App Service, Application Insights, Search Service and the Application Service Plan*) **is hosted in the same region** as the QnA Maker Service itself.

Since the QnA Maker service can only be hosted in West US (*as far a I know and was able to find*: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services?page=2), the current workaround for this case is to create a new QnA Maker service with the resource group being hosted in the West US region. Then the creation of a knowledge base should work as always.

PS: seems like this issues was already reported, but the problem still occurs for me from time to time (https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-faqplusplus-app/issues/71)

Answer (score 0):

My resources and resource group were all in West US but I still got the same "No Endpoint keys found." error.

Eventually I figured out that the issue was related to my subscription levels. Make sure that they are all the same for all your created resources.

If you are using the deploy.ps1 script in the Virtual Assistant VS template, open the file at `.\Deployment\Resources\template.json`

That is a template for the resource creation. You can look through it to see exactly which resources will be created and what parameters are sent to Azure for each of the resources.

I am using a My Visual Studio subscription so it is registered as a free tier in Azure. What worked for me, is that I had to update all the "standard" subscriptions to free in the `Parameters` JSON array. I didn't update anything lower down for fear that it might interfere with the creation process too much.

An example is the `appServicePlanSku` parameter. It was set to

```
"appServicePlanSku": {
  "type": "object",
  "defaultValue": {
    "tier": "Standard",
    "name": "S1"
  }
}
```

I updated it to

```
"appServicePlanSku": {
  "type": "object",
  "defaultValue": {
    "tier": "Free",
    "name": "F0"
  }
}
```

I made multiple of these updates in the parameters array. After those changes, deleting the resource group for the 100th time and running the deployment script again, it worked.